# Why can't I use options '--reverse' and '--graph' together?

Tags: git

`fatal: options '--reverse' and '--graph' cannot be used together`

What's the reason? I'm trying to think if there could be a technical reason, if maybe it just wouldn't look good or whatever but I can't think of anything.

The check is under

```
    /*
     * Limitations on the graph functionality
     */
```

I did see an explanation for `-g/--walk-reflogs` and `--reverse`

```
Don't allow combination of -g and --reverse as it doesn't work
The --walk-reflogs logic and the --reverse logic are completely
incompatible with one another.  Attempting to use both at the same
time leads to confusing results that sometimes violates the user's
formatting options or ignores the user's request to see the reflog
message and timestamp.

Unfortunately the implementation of both of these features is glued
onto the side of the revision walking machinary in such a way that
they are probably not going to be easy to make them compatible with
each other.  Rather than offering the user confusing results we are
better off bailing out with an error message until such a time as
the implementations can be refactored to be compatible.

Signed-off-by: Shawn O. Pearce <spearce@spearce.org>
Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
```

Is `--graph` similar?

Comment: No explanation [in the code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6269f8eaad054a02517f5e03873726e84a032d8e/revision.c#L3008) as well. My guess is that since `--graph` [requires to walk the revision graph](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_description) on its own way, it would be hard to make it compatible with `--reverse` which works in another way (like `--walk-reflogs`), so they just disable it.